# Preferred ODBC DSN in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

We are using a third party software which we have to connect to SQL Server. We are using SQL Server DSN connection, but the third party tool suggested that we have to use SQL Server native client DSN for the better performance.

Please suggest which DSN connection would be preferred SQL Server or SQL Server native client.

Comment: If ever possible, use the **SQL Server Native Client**

Answer (score 0):

Yes always try to use SQL server native client for this. you could download this microsoft site.
For 2008 R2 you need to use SQL SERVER NATIVE CLIENT 10.0  and you could download this form [download link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj0iIn2gtHLAhXPkY4KHew6ByIQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgo.microsoft.com%2Ffwlink%2F%3FLinkID%3D188401%26clcid%3D0x409&usg=AFQjCNGa5uTvxg0A8_pBTEs6DnDlU8yS2Q&sig2=jqlS4OtMcldJ6nSm0ACKeg)
you was asking about which DSN connection would be proffered. I think this depend on your sql server version.